# my shell script throwing an error for the file, where I have full permissions to read/write on the directory

Tags: command-line, scripts

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

date_today=`date +"%Y%m%d"`


file_dir="/home/reports/archive"

v_outdir="/home/report/work"

v_file=$(${file_dir}/abc.*.xyz)

wc -l ${v_file}|sed '1d' | awk -F" " '{print $2","$1}'  >> 
${v_outdir}/output.txt 2>&1


cat ${v_outdir}/output.txt
```

while executing the above getting below error  , I have full permission on this directory

```bash
error : /home/reports/archive/abc.S60286.RE.xyz: Permission denied
```

Comment: looks like you're getting denied reading a file, not writing output.

Comment: `v_file=$(${file_dir}/abc.*.xyz)` is going to try to *execute* the result of `${file_dir}/abc.*.xyz`